# Texto selecionável sem cursor (marcador) no Delphi

Tags: delphi

Queria saber se alguém conhece algum componente do Delphi onde possa colocar um texto via programação e que esse texto possa ser selecionado pelo usuário, mas, ao clicar no texto não mostre cursor (marcador) no componente.

Por exemplo, um texto em uma página da internet, o usuário pode selecionar, mas se ele apenas clicar no texto não irá aparecer cursor.

Sei que dá para remover o cursor de `TMemo`, mas eu queria saber se existe algum componente propriamente para esta finalidade.

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O componente LabelEdit permite mudar padronizar o cursor conforme sua necessidade e não permite edição dos dados!

Era isso que você queria? Espero ter ajudado!